# Rails "Cannot read termcap database;"

Tags: macos, zsh, ruby, iterm2, ruby-on-rails

Whenever I start my rails console I'm running into two problems:

1. I'm getting these cryptic errors messages.
2. My control-L isn't working (it's intended use it to clear the screen)

Console output:

```
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 69986
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
Cannot read termcap database;
using dumb terminal settings.
irb(main):001:0>
```

How do I fix my "termcap database" and also get my ctl-L back?

I'm macOS with iTerm2 using zsh. Please let me know if any more info will help :)

Comment: This will probably fix your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37847933/2995613

Comment: I got the same error just after installation globalize gem: https://github.com/globalize/globalize. Reproduced n macOS, Ruby 2.4.0, Rails 5.1.5 on a fresh Rails app.

Answer (score -3):

I had this exact same problem. I ran bundle exec rails c from command line and problem solved. After exit and rails c, the warning was gone.

Comment: I was getting the exact same message on rails c.  The problem was solved after running bundle exec rails c.  Maybe it would work for poster too, or some other person who finds this thread.